# WebResponse In JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to read www.abc.com - page(view source) from www.xyz.com, may be cross domain problem also come.

This is possible in code behind by using WebRequest, WebResponse, Stream i am able to read.

But this same thing i want to do in JavaScript or jQuery is it possible?  Can u help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Eg: By this we can read in cs page, but same thing i want in jquery

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.abc.com");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
    string html = String.Empty;
    Uri pgetpage = new Uri(host);
    if (pgetpage.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns && (!(pgetpage.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Unknown)))
    {
        host = "http://" + pgetpage.Host.Replace("www.", "") + "/";
    }
    string getUrl1 = host;
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Longer answer: if you can add stuff on the foreign server or they allow CORS or have a JSONP api then you will have a better chance

Answer (score 1):

Not in normal cases, because of same origin policy (cross domain access).

If you can modify responses on other server you should be able to uses CORS or other x-domain solutions.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this

```
$.get('www.xyz.com', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I have tried <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("MyName");
    $.get('www.google.com', function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
    
</script> But i am not getting any alert

Comment: i am getting first alert but not second alert

Comment: The [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids this.

Comment: It will only work if you have control of the response buffer that is returned from the web server.